# How can I insert or store multiple ids in a single column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5.1

How can I insert or save multiple ids as comma separated e.g (2,5,8,10) values in single column in database for many to many relationship? I am using active admin for resource management.

Comment: When ever you want to use many to many relationship then use "has_and_belongs_to_many" association . So you can create join table for 2 models.

Comment: true what @user3678149 points out. for whatever weird usecase you might have, there are array-types in postgres than could be used for storing such things.

Comment: When you get this up and running you may want to do a performance test. I cant imagine a serialized join performing as well is a standard many to many.

Comment: Previous comments are correct. In general, you don't want to serialize multiple ids like that in a single column. The standard solution is to use an intermediate table—a "join table"—to associate records like this. See [here](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3451-Has-Many-Through-and-Has-and-Belongs-to-Many-in-Rails-5) for more.